# kotlin RecyclerView play sound

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, playsound

I want to play a sound with a button.
Here is my code (adapter.kt)

```
package com.example.koszono

import android.content.Intent
import android.media.MediaPlayer
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.recycler_row.view.*

class Adapter (val koszones: ArrayList<String>,
            val hangList : ArrayList<Int>): RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.KoszonesVH>()       {
class KoszonesVH (itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){


}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): KoszonesVH {
    val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_row, parent, false)
    return KoszonesVH(itemView)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: KoszonesVH, position: Int) {
    holder.itemView.recycler_textView.text = koszones.get(position)


    var mMediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = null
    holder.itemView.recycler_play.setOnClickListener {

        if (mMediaPlayer == null) {
            mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.hello)
            mMediaPlayer!!.isLooping = false
            mMediaPlayer!!.start()
        } else mMediaPlayer!!.start()



    }







    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent (holder.itemView.context, activity_tartalom::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("koszones", koszones.get(position))
        intent.putExtra("hang_intent", hangList.get(position))
        holder.itemView.context.startActivity(intent)
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return koszones.size
}
}
```

error code: None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:
public open fun create(p0: Context!, p1: Uri!): MediaPlayer! defined in android.media.MediaPlayer
public open fun create(p0: Context!, p1: Int): MediaPlayer! defined in android.media.MediaPlayer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is the `this` param in the Mediaplayer create method, because the param must be a context but your `this` is an adapter, so:

```
MediaPlayer.create(holder.itemView.context, R.raw.hello)
```